# Two differents longtable, but same column witdh

Tags: tables, longtable, columns

I would like to create two differents longtables, with the same width of columns from one longtable to an other other.

Here some specifities.

1. The longtable have the same number of columns
2. The content of the lastest column have the same size from one header to an other one.
3. Only the content of the first columns could have different size

I would like the size of the first columns be the same from table to an another one, the size should be the max of "autocalculated size".

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
Head & 1 \\
\endhead
text & other
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
Head & 2 \\
\endhead
longer text & other
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63535/align-columns-in-multiple-tables/63544#63544

Comment: thnaks! That is perfetc. I didn't think in terme of column alignment, but in term of column widht. I think you can deleted this question, if you want.