# Align columns in multiple tables - again

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I want to align the columns of multiple `longtable`s.

David Carlisle already provided [a solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63535/align-columns-in-multiple-tables) over a decade ago, but it is not working (any longer), if the last table is narrower than the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\makeatletter
\def\dontchopLT{\let\LT@entry@chop\relax}
\def\resumeLT{%
\let\zzz\stepcounter
\def\yyy{LT@tables}
\def\stepcounter##1{%
  \def\xxx{##1}%
  \ifx\xxx\yyy\else\zzz{##1}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\dontchopLT
\begin{longtable}{ll}
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz & 10 \\
5 & 6 \\
\end{longtable}}

{\resumeLT
\begin{longtable}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can someone figure what is wrong?

Comment: If you look at the aux file, `\LT@i` is being redefined as what would narmally be `\LT@ii`, except the {1} (chunk number?) is reset to {2}.  But the redefinition loses all the information from `\LT@i`.

Comment: actually I'm not sure it ever worked, as @JohnKormylo says I reset the main counter but the chunk counter is out of sync, I may look at that at the weekend. essentially this is a duplicate but no harm in repositing it gives others a chance to answer rather than relying on a comment just to me in the old question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fear that no one else has the knowledge to solve this problem. Perhaps this could be solved as a request for a new functionality of the package?

Comment: it can't just be me in 30+years that can do this, you can make a feature request, but my time is limited a feature request in github less likely to get lost than one here, but maybe someone will answer here...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I just realised that there is no place to put a feature request as there is no github longtable project. I will just give up.

Comment: there are two github repositories for longtable the latex3/latex2e repository (as longtable is part of the core tools release) or a more speculative repository under davidcarlisle/dpctex for a possible more radical longtable v5 that may or may not ever happen.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks